# Displaying Data from SQL in TextBox by clicking ComboBox item in Visual Basic 2012

Tags: sql, combobox, textbox

I have three columns in SQL, which I want the data displayed in three textboxes by clicking an item in ComboBox.

The issue is not really displaying. I can save the data fine and display. However, one of the text fields will only show one cell and not update when a different item is selected. Hope this is making sense.

Here is the code I have for saving:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\INFLOWSQL;Initial Catalog=RioDiary;Integrated Security=True"


    Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    mycommand.Connection = myconnect
    mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyDiary (Title, DiaryContent, DiaryDate) VALUES (@Title, @DiaryContent, @DiaryDate)"
    myconnect.Open()

    Try
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@DiaryContent", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@DiaryDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text

        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Success")
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
```

And here is the code for displaying in form1:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Dim max As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'RioDiaryDataSet5.MyDiary' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.MyDiaryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.RioDiaryDataSet5.MyDiary)
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("  Data Source=.\INFLOWSQL;Initial Catalog=RioDiary;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Title,DiaryContent,DiaryDate FROM MyDiary ")
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        cmd.Connection = con
        da.Fill(ds, "MyDiary")

        con.Open()

        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Title'"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "DiaryContent"
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewEntryToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewEntryToolStripMenuItem.Click
        AddEntry.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged



        If (Not Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue Is Nothing) Then
            Me.TextBox2.Text = ComboBox1.Text
            Me.TextBox3.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString


        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
      If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("DiaryDate").ToString()  'Where ColumnName is the Field from the DB that you want to display

    End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see from the code, I want to display Title and DiaryContent in two separate textboxes by clicking on Title in the Combobox. This works fine.
The issue I have is DiaryDate only shows the first entry and does not update when selecting the Item from ComboBox.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to play with ComboBox's `SelectedItem` property. Since ComboBox's DataSource is `DataTable` here, `SelectedItem` of ComboBox represent a row in `DataTable`. Given `DataRow` in hand, you can display value of any column of `DataRow` in TextBoxes :

```
........
If (Not Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then
    Dim SelectedItem = TryCast(comboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    Me.TextBox1.Text = SelectedItem.Row("Title").ToString()
    Me.TextBox2.Text = SelectedItem.Row("DiaryContent").ToString()
    Me.TextBox3.Text = SelectedItem.Row("DiaryDate").ToString()
End If
........
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried what you said and got errors about the System.Data.Row cannot be converted to string and also Identifier Expected in ["Title"] etc...

Comment: Updated my answer, my bad, was confused with C# syntax

Comment: I could kiss you. lol Thank you so much Har07. Works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. Looking at you profile picture, argh.. can't imagine that. lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=thee-pc;Initial Catalog=jobportal;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Try
        cn.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "select * from Register"
        cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Dim id = reader.Item("cid")
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(id)
        End While
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=thee-pc;Initial Catalog=jobportal;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Try
        cn.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "select * from register where cid ='" + ComboBox1.Text + "'"
        cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            TextBox1.Text = reader.Item("cname")
            TextBox2.Text = reader.Item("dob")

        End While
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```